# How can I submit pronunciation improvements for Google Translate?

Tags: google-translate

Google translate has an option named *Improve this translation* which is claimed to be a tool to improve translation quality by users' feedback.

But is there also away to make Google translate aware of its pronunciation mistakes?
For example it puts the stress of word `attempt` on the first syllable which is wrong:
[attempt - Google translate](https://translate.google.ca/#en/en/attempt)

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

There does not seem to be a way to submit pronunciation improvements. The best you can do is to use the *Send feedback* link in the bottom of the screen.